# Automatically create a new row conditional on a new unique entry

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets in my workbook -- "Source" and "Results." I'd like to automate new row creation in "Results."

"Source" includes individual entries into a Google Form for hours worked on my team -- so for each date, each team member has their own distinct line on the form that includes 1) Date Worked (Column B), 2) Name (Column C), 3) Hours Worked (Column D).  (Column A is the Google Form timestamp, which is irrelevant here since team members fill out the form after the "Date Worked.")

My Results page is a matrix, with Column A being "Date Worked," and the remainder of the columns being my team members (i.e., each team member has their own column).  The values in the matrix are Hours Worked, and I currently have a SUMIFS formula for each team member that auto-fills Hours Worked conditional on Date Worked and Name. However, I need to manually enter the date in the "Date Worked" column.

Is there any way to automatically populate the "Date Worked" column each time a new date is entered?  Simply adding a new row to Results each time a new row is added to Source doesn't work, since there are multiple entries in Source for the same date.

Here's a mock-up of the spreadsheet (actually using AVERAGEIFS here, not SUMIFS -- ignore that): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dsaMYsJeZl2o_rNTLwaVhnEehFvAKRMXghAJeEK220s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So what's it going to be... [excel-vba] or [google-spreadsheet-api]? While there are similarities in some worksheet functions, what you are asking is **completely** different for the two platforms.

Comment: Preferably [google-spreadsheet-api].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pivot table to summarize the workhours. No scripting is required.

Here is a [revised version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AzpFmQdQJOIF8_x6sB1JWG1aQVbe3qXXx3kZn0R92gM/edit?usp=sharing) of your file

Answer (score 0):

Found that pivot table works, but the simple solution I ended up implementing was a UNIQUE function. Haven't run into problems with it thus far.